# boost::lambda : _1 is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, boost, stl, lambda

I'd like to fullfill a set of strings, from a list of classes which have such string as an attribute (public getter available).

I'd like to do it using lambda expressions and std::for_each.

I was thinking about something like :

```
class Foo
{
    const std::string& getMe() const;
}

...
std::list<Foo> foos; // Let's image the list is not empty
std::set<std::string> strings; // The set to be filled

using namespace boost::lambda;
std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(), bind(
    std::set<std::string>::insert, &strings, _1::getMe()));
```

But, I get this error at compile time:

> _1 is not a class or namespace

Thanks.

Comment: yes, you're missing explaining what's the problem you have if any

Comment: @andy_t just wondering if this could work, since I'm not inserting _1 placeholder directly but I'm calling a method on it.

Comment: @AndyT : yes, I have a compilation error (added it in the question). Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const void* getMe() const
    {
        return this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<Foo> foos(10);
    std::set<const void*> addresses; // The set to be filled

    using boost::bind;
    std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(), bind(
        &std::set<const void*>::insert, &addresses, bind(&Foo::getMe, _1)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work ? (does not compile to me)

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. Tested it in VC++10, boost 1.50